# Can a Java function's parameter require optional interfaces?

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I have two interfaces in Java (version 8) which are very similar.
I cannot change the interfaces and cannot change the classes which implement them.

```java
public interface A {
    int get();
}

public interface B {
    int get();
    int somethingelse();
}
```

Now I have a function that its implementation fits both interfaces (almost).
I want it to do something like that:

```java
public int foo((A | B) p) {
    int ret = 0;
    if (p instanceof B) {
        ret = p.somthingelse();
    }
    return ret + p.get();
}
```

I don't want to use inspection because this function is on the main pipeline of my program.
I want it to have good performance.
Is it possible to do this in Java?

### Edit:

A simple solution will be to copy/paste `foo()` and implement it differently for each interface.
But in reality `foo()` and the interfaces are much longer than that and I'm trying to avoid code duplication.

Comment: A and B have nothing in common. So create two foo() methods: one which takes a B, and one which takes an A. Also, don't make assumptions on the cause of a performance issue until you have a performance issue, and you have verified this assumption by measurements.

Comment: @JBNizet A and B have `get()` in common. This is off course a simplified example. In reality, they have more functions in common.

Comment: No, they don't. B doesn't extend A. So they just happen to have a method that has the same signature and return type. If every B is supposed to be an A, then B should extend A.

Comment: Can you change the `foo()` method and the calls to it?

Comment: @JBNizet Yes. But I could imagine creating an interface which is the intersection of both. That is basically what I'm trying to understand: can I create such a fictional interface?

Comment: @ernest_k I'm willing to consider changing `foo()` and the calls to it if this will result in an elegant solution that avoids code duplication.

Comment: A lot of this is what functional interfaces are for.  Even if they have nothing in common, do they look at the same contextual parameters?  Can they simply be wrapped in a `Runnable`?  Do they each supply a `String` as an output (`Supplier<String>`)?  Etc.  You can abstract to the appropriate level (or define your own functional interface if none suffice) to resolve this.

Comment: @user2478398 Have you looked at ernest_k answer? I think that it is what you are talking about.

Comment: @LiranFunaro If they(both the interfaces) have something in common, why not extract it to a parent and further extend it? Aside: `public` accessor is redundant for interface methods. And did you mean `instanceof` instead of `implements`?

Comment: @Naman Because at least one of the interfaces is not implemented by me (`java.nio.ByteBuffer`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's unfortunately no way to create that kind of retroactive relationship between two unrelated types.

If you can change `foo()` and its invocations, you could be able to make use of functional interfaces matching the signatures that you invoke inside `foo`. I'm using `IntSupplier` here, with corresponding lambda expressions using concrete implementations of `A` and `B`.

Say you have these implementations:

```
class AImpl implements A {
     //implementation
}
class BImpl implements B {
     //implementation
}
```

You can change `foo` to something like:

```
public int foo(IntSupplier get, IntSupplier somethingElse) {
    int ret = 0;
    if (somethingElse != null) {
        ret = somethingElse.getAsInt();
    }
    return ret + get.getAsInt();
}
```

And call it this way:

```
A a = new AImpl();
B b = new BImpl();

int result = this.foo(a::get, b::somethingelse);
```

Comment: Interesting solution! This can be extended to a solution that does not requires changes to foo's signature.
Simply write two implementations to `foo()` for each interface and then call your `foo()` with matching suppliers. Do you want to add this or would you like me to edit your answer?

Comment: @LiranFunaro Right. I was limited by the constraint that the `if` logic must remain inside `foo()`. But yes, you can definitely do that if it's appropriate.

Comment: Sorry, but there is very little that I can relate to the question and the `IntSupplier` suggestion in this answer. Additionally, the `BImpl`(or simply `B`) cannot be used as a FunctionalInterface, given more than one abstract method.  Further, from [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59237393/can-a-java-functions-parameter-require-optional-interfaces#comment104686442_59237393), the statement "*two unrelated types*" doesn't hold true. Nitpick: `IntSupplier get` is unused in your code.

Comment: @Naman Thanks for your view. `B` isn't being used as a functional interface. `b:somethingelse` is a method reference for `IntSupplier` in this case (I'd suggest you compile the code). And yes, `A` and `B` are two completely unrelated types. And about the solution overall, I think I understand that you find it a little awkward. I can suppose that there are finer approaches, but not many that shun the refactoring that the OP can't afford.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can imagine is this:

```
public int foo(A p) {
    return internal_foo(p);
}

public int foo(B p) {
    return internal_foo(p);
}

private int internal_foo(Object p) {
    if (p instanceof A) {
        return ((A)p).get();
    }
    if (p instanceof B) {
        B b = (B)p;
        ret = b.somthingelse();
        return ret + b.get();
    }
    throw new ClassCastException("Wrong type");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem with this is that the function implementation is much longer than that. So I'll have to copy/paste a lot of code, which is what I'm trying to avoid :)

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, Java doesn't support this directly, but you could manually create a "type-union wrapper". Something like this:

```
abstract class AorB {
    public static AorB wrap(A a) {
        return new AWrapper(a);
    }

    public static AorB wrap(B b) {
        return new BWrapper(b);
    }

    abstract int get();
    abstract int somethingElse();
}

class AWrapper extends AorB {
    private final A a;

    AWrapper(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    int get() {
        return a.get();
    }

    @Override
    int somethingElse() {
        return 0;
    }
}

class BWrapper extends AorB {
    private final B b;

    BWrapper(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    int get() {
        return b.get();
    }

    @Override
    int somethingElse() {
        return b.somethingElse();
    }
}

// and then

public int foo(A a) {
    return fooImpl(AorB.wrap(a));
}

public int foo(B b) {
    return fooImpl(AorB.wrap(b));
}

int fooImpl(AorB p) {
    return p.get() + p.somethingElse();
}
```

You could also add some inspection functions like `hasSomethingElse()`, if there's no appropriate default value to return, like the `0` above..

Comment: I would accept this answer too if I could accept two answers.